# Operation must use an updatable query

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2016

I am trying to update a column in one table to set its value to the count of records in another table.  This produces the error:

> Operation must use an updateable query.

Query:

```
UPDATE Tracking SET BatchCount = (Select Count(*) from Batch)
WHERE ReportingDate=Date();
```

It seems Access does not like the `Select Count(*) from Batch` sub-query.   If I replace it with a literal value, it works fine.

Any suggestions to resolve this issue is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately this is an inherent restriction of the JET database engine used by MS Access: no part of an `update` query may use aggregation, else the resulting recordset is not updateable.

---

There are a couple of workarounds:

You can use a domain aggregate function, such as [`DCount`](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/dcount-function-f6b5d78b-ad0b-4e42-be7a-11a64acbf3d3):

```sql
update tracking set batchcount = dcount("*", "Batch")
where reportingdate = date();
```

Alternatively, you can use a temporary table to store the result of the count, and then update the records using the value held in the table, e.g.

```sql
select count(*) as cnt into temptable from batch
```

```sql
update tracking, temptable set tracking.batchcount = temptable.cnt
where tracking.reportingdate = date();
```