# Updating a Table using a calculated field in a query

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have 2 tables:

- T1: overall info regarding some transaction
- T2: breakdown of the transaction by item and the status of where it is (currently "open" vs "closed")

I have to run a query that determines based on the status in T2, what the overall status of the transaction is in T1 (i.e., if there are 2 line items, and 1 is "open" and the other is "closed" the over all status is "open" where I do this via `iif`: open-1 closed-0, sum them by ID, and then if > 0, "open", otherwise "closed")

I want to run an update query that updates the status column (linked by the ID). So far I have tried:

```
UPDATE [T1] INNER JOIN [Query1] ON [Query1].[ID] = [T1].[ID] 
SET [Query1].[Overall Status] = [T1].[Overall Status];`
```

Query1 is defined as:

```
SELECT [T1].[ID], IIf((Sum(IIf([T2].[Status]="Closed",0,1)))=0,"Closed","Open") AS [Overall Status] 
FROM [T1] INNER JOIN [T2] ON [T1].[ID] = [T2].[ID] 
GROUP BY [T1].[ID];
```

I always get the error

> "Operation must use an updateable query"

Unfortunately, this is being done in MS Access, but any suggestions would be great!

Comment: Are you wanting to update the value in the `[Query1]` output or the column in table `[T1]`. Currently this is attempting (and failing) to do the former.

Comment: Hi I am attempting to update the value in the table. @JNevill

Comment: Query 1 is 
`SELECT [T1].[ID], IIf((Sum(IIf([T2].[Status]="Closed",0,1)))=0,"Closed","Open") AS [Overall Status]
FROM [T1] INNER JOIN [T2] ON [T1].[ID] = [T2].[ID]
GROUP BY [T1].[ID];`

@LeeMac

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Operation must use an updatable query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57124762/operation-must-use-an-updatable-query)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Update queries](http://allenbrowne.com/ser-61.html) cannot use an underlying aggregate query in its source as your *Query1* shows. Also, you cannot update a column in query as your `SET` clause indicates.

Until one day, Access SQL meets modern, standard ANSI rules like its RDBMS peers as [suggested](https://access.uservoice.com/forums/319956-access-desktop-application/suggestions/37193662-upgrade-access-sql-dialect-to-current-ansi-standar) (please vote at link, no need to login), consider domain aggregates like `DCount` wrapped in `IIF` expression. However, this is akin to a correlated aggregate subquery which may reduce performance.

```
UPDATE [T1]
SET [T1].[Overall Status] = IIF(NZ(DCount("*",
                                          "[T2]", 
                                          "ID='" & [T1].ID & "' AND ([Status]<>'Closed' 
                                                                     AND [Status] IS NOT NULL)")=0,
                                'Closed',
                                'Open')
```

Comment: Hi! Thank you so much, as so far, this is the closest this has gotten to working. Unfortunately, its giving me an error regarding a type conversion error. 



Based on some quick googling, i'm guessing a data type mismatch. As this column is pretty much left alone otherwise, i was thinking it would be best to change the data type of the "overall status" to fit query you ran. Do you know how to work around this?(and or what the data type is now?)

Comment: What is the data type of *Overall Status* in the `T1` table? It must be text to receive *Closed* and *Open* values. If this is not the issue, try wrapping `DCount` in `NZ()`. See edit.

Comment: the data type is "short text"
with the update, it is still giving the same error

Comment: Even with `NZ()`? is IDs for both table the same type, ideally integers?

Comment: they are both short text (i chose that since "open" vs "closed")
why integer? ( i can easily change them if needed, as the columns are currently empty)
I copied the code from above, including NZ() and it is still giving the error

Comment: That's the issue. Since IDs are text, they need quotes wrapped around in `DCount`. See edit.

Comment: Thank you! it worked!

one last thing- it is reading nulls automatically as closed, is there a quick fix to make them "open" if there are nulls?

Comment: See update checking for `NULL` in criteria of `DCount`.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have the sample data but the query you are looking for is below

```
UPDATE [T1]
INNER JOIN INNER JOIN [Query1] ON [Query1].[ID] = [T1].[ID]
SET [T1].[Overall Status] = [Query1].[Overall Status]
```

Comment: Unfortunately this is not valid SQL in MS Access.

Comment: Indeed @Lee, Corrected the query for MSAccess

Comment: You have essentially posted the SQL included in the original question... The likely issue is that `Query1` contains aggregation.

Comment: To me the issue was that he is updating T1 and the operation he was doing what like: [Query1].[Overall Status] = [T1].[Overall Status]. if T1 is being updated, that is a field from t1 that should be updated not the other way around

Comment: You may be right - we'll have to see how the OP responds.

Answer (score 0):

Given the logic of your existing query, one possible way around resorting to a domain aggregate function (such as `DCount` or `DSum`) might be to first initialise the statuses to `Closed` using:

```
update t1 set t1.status = 'Closed'
```

And then update those for which there exists at least one `Open` record in `t2` using:

```
update t1 inner join t2 on t1.id = t2.id
set t1.status = 'Open'
where t2.status = 'Open'
```

I believe this will yield the desired result.